# How do you stub a method that accepts an IEnumerable in RhinoMocks?

Tags: c#, unit-testing, rhino-mocks

I've got a SqlLayer class I'm trying to Mock that has a GetDataReader method that accepts a string query and an IEnumerable of SqlParameters. I've tried stubbing out the method call like this:

```
var parameters = new SqlParameter[] {}
mockSqlLayer.Stub(x => x.GetDataReader(spaceConsumedQuery, parameters)).Return(MockDataReader());
```

But the test is returning a NullReferenceException, I assume because the signature isn't resolving correctly, and can't find the stub. 
The method signature I'm trying to call looks like this:

```
public IDataReader GetDataReader(string commandText, IEnumerable<SqlParameter> parameters)
```

Comment: Try with `var parameters = Enumerable.Empty<SqlParameter>()` and see if you still get the error

Comment: Still got the same error in the same spot.

Comment: In that case the type isn't your problem.

Comment: Closed as dupe of [the canonical NRE answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4660142/what-is-a-nullreferenceexception-and-how-do-i-fix-it) but reopening as unsure it is.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The argument matcher would need to be loosened to allow for the invocation to behave as expected.

```
mockSqlLayer
    .Stub(_ => _.GetDataReader(spaceConsumedQuery, Arg<IEnumerable<SqlParameter>>.Is.Anything))
    .Return(MockDataReader());
```

The code used originally would need to use the same object reference for the invocation to match.

The assumption here is that the value in variable `spaceConsumedQuery` is the same one used when exercising the subject under test.

If not,  then `Arg<string>.Is.Anything` could be used to loosen that match as well.